# Scrapy "download_latency" unit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Can someone tell me what is the Unit for `download_latency` in scrapy framework? Is it secs?

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.5/topics/request-response.html#download-latency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is seconds as a `float`.

[It is calculated using `time.time()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/016c7e92d1d2893e7a8ce61c7f2e76818e71d019/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L363).